# How to use beginBackgroundTask and endBackgroundTask in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, ios-simulator

I am developing an iOS application on Swift. I am on simulator and I would like to update the data of a user when he leaves the application.
Here is the code:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application : UIApplication){
        //We update user Data
        let taskId = application.beginBackgroundTask {}
        Users.updateUsersData {
           application.endBackgroundTask(taskId)
        }
    }
```

```
static func updateUsersData(completion : @escaping () -> Void) {
        let update : [String : Any] = [
            "Users/\(userId!)/numberOfGame" : (Users.numberOfGame)!,
            "Users/\(userId!)/numberOfWin" : (Users.numberOfWin)!
        ]
        
        dbRef.updateChildValues(update){
            (error,dbRef) in
            completion()
        }
    }
```

Only when I close the application from the simulator, the applicationWillTerminate function is called but it finishes before the writing in updateUserData finishes. It is normal because updateChildValues is asynchronous but I wait, at no time the writing occurs. This may be because I'm doing my update in applicationWillTerminate and not in applicationDidEnterBackground, which would give the OS more time to accept the timeout request, but the problem is that applicationDidEnterBackground is never called (I don't know why).

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks !

Comment: This isn't a very good strategy. There is no guarantee that `applicationWillTerminate` will be called and if it is, you don't have very much time to do any work.  You should save data as you go rather than waiting for application termination. It doesn't look like you are saving a lot of data so the network traffic would be insignificant.

Comment: Yes, but updating as we go along would increase the number of requests considerably. Which is not very optimized

Comment: Then you could use a timer to add some hysteresis; when there is updated information start a 30 second timer (or whatever is appropriate). If the data is updated before the timer expires, restart the timer. If the timer expires update the server. Another approach would be to update the server when your app moves to the background; this indicates the user has stopped using your app.  You could combine these two approaches.

Comment: Yes this function is called applicationDidEnterBackground, the problem is that on my simulator it seems never to be called

Comment: It will be called when you press the home button (or swipe up on a face id device)